# XML: How to send stream from external encoder to Adobe Media Server?

Tags: xml, adobe, flash

I am using a Digital Rapids encoder to stream (RTMP). I would like to install a flash server in the same VLAN to read the stream. I therefore downloaded Adobe Media Server and wish to stream towards the integrated Adobe Sample Video Player. However, the Digital Rapids doesn't recognize my destination Server URL. I guess it is because of a port issue.

Checking the ports situation on my AMS Server (cmd -> netstat -an), I realise port 1935 (which receives RTMP) is only listening locally (127.0.0.1:1935) instead of to the exterior (I would like to have 0.0.0.0:1935). The application does not seem to have forced the port to open (I don't have any firewall).

Looking into the xml code (../conf/*defaultRoot*/*defaultVHost*/Vhost.xml), it looks like the app only runs locally rather than remotely:

```
<Proxy>
    <!-- A vhost may be configured to run apps locally or remotely.  -->
    <!-- A vhost that is not explicitly defined gets aliased to      -->
    <!-- the default vhost and is configured as such. A proxy server -->
    <!-- runs all its apps remotely, while a normal server runs all  -->
    <!-- its apps locally. The following parameter defines whether   -->
    <!-- this vhost is running local or remote apps, the default is  -->
    <!-- local. It may be set to either local or remote              -->

    <Mode>local</Mode>
        <RequestTimeout>2</RequestTimeout>
    <Anonymous>false</Anonymous>
    <CacheDir enabled="false" useAppName="true">            
        <Path></Path>
        <MaxSize>32</MaxSize>
    </CacheDir>
    <LocalAddress></LocalAddress>
    <RouteTable protocol="">
        <RouteEntry></RouteEntry>
    </RouteTable>
    <EdgeAutoDiscovery>
        <Enabled>false</Enabled>
        <AllowOverride>true</AllowOverride>
        <WaitTime>1000</WaitTime>
    </EdgeAutoDiscovery>

    <!--
    <SSL>
        <SSLVerifyCertificate>true</SSLVerifyCertificate>
        <SSLCACertificatePath></SSLCACertificatePath>
        <SSLCACertificateFile></SSLCACertificateFile>
        <SSLVerifyDepth>9</SSLVerifyDepth>
        <SSLCipherSuite>ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH</SSLCipherSuite>
    </SSL>
    -->
    <AggregateMessages enabled="true">
        <!-- <MaxAggMsgSize>65536</MaxAggMsgSize> -->

        <!-- <MaxAggMsgDuration>10000</MaxAggMsgDuration >      -->
    </AggregateMessages>
</Proxy>
```

Do you have any suggestions or advice be code-wise or simple configuration?

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the source of the issue. It isn't code based. It turns out another application requiring access to port 1935 was already installed on my server, and had priority over the AMS. I uninstalled it, and the AMS now receives the stream. Hope this helps!